# ASP.net Version 4 with IIS7

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-7.5

I am currently developing an ASP.net application which was started in version .Net framework version 3.5. This worked fine without problems. However, I have now realised I need to use .Net framework version 4. When I change the project to be a .net 4 application and I try to run the web app from visual studio 2010 it displays

> Unable to start debugging on the web
>   server. See help for common
>   configuration errors. Running the web
>   page outside the debugger may provide
>   more information.
>
> Make sure the server is operating
>   properly...

I have changed the application pool for the web app to be .Net version 4 with integrated code. Visual studio still displays the error and when I try to run the web app from outside visual studio, directly running it from the browser I get an IIS error message which says

HTTP Error 500.21 Internal Server Error
Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

This is running IIS7 on Windows 7.

Does anyone have any solutions as to how I can fix this problem

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same issue 2 days ago. I'm willing to bet it's because you installed IIS after installing .NET 4.0.

You can fix this by re-installing .NET

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe –i
```

Or for 32bit

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe –i
```

Edit: Here's the link I found and used the other day.

http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/fix-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-iis7